# How do I detect if an AP has WDS enabled?

Tags: networking

I want to create a [WDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system) client for an Access Point. Problem is, I'm not sure if the Access Point is a WDS access point or not. Is there a method of detecting this from the cli or with a tool? If so which tool would help me determine this?

Comment: WDS most likely requires 4 addresses mode. AP usually is using 3 addresses mode and both can't work together (but you can have the system provide two: one "normal" and one for wds). check this Q/A: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header . I hope this will give you ideas.